# How to apply a property to a control, without affecting its children

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've got a TreeView which has highlighting disabled like so:

```
<TreeView Name="tvFilters" Margin="0,10,0,10" Background="White" BorderBrush="White">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <!-- Disables the blue highlighting when a TreeViewItem is clicked -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}">
                    Transparent
                </SolidColorBrush> 
            </TreeView.Resources>
 </TreeView>
```

**EDIT:** This is part of my TreeView - notice the gray area that has developed after clicking on a TreeViewItem:

[image]

Here is another:

[image]

Comment: I assume you will have to style your `TreeView`, instead of setting the `HighlightBrushKey` for the scope of the whole `TreeView`...

Comment: Could you please elaborate @Spontifixus ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the desired behavior you will need to provide a new default style and template for the `TreeViewItem`. Within this template you can then change the color of the background for highlighted items, without influencing the background for all children of the `TreeViewItem`.

You can find an example for a style including a template in the MSDN: [TreeViewItem ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms788727(v=vs.90).aspx).

### First step: Get the styles into your application

You will need to make the styles and templates available for your `TreeView`. Therefore copy the XAML from the website and paste it into the Resources-section of your `TreeView`:

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvFilters" ...>
    <TreeView.Resources>

        <!-- paste copied styles here -->

    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

**NOTE:** Ensure you also copy the `SolidColorBrush` named `GlyphBrush` at the bottom of the provided example. Otherwise your code won't work.

### Second step: Modify the code so it fits your needs

To make the code work as you wish you will need to make some modifications.

1. Remove `x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"` from the following line

   ```
   <Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
   ```

   so that it looks like

   ```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
   ```

   That will apply the style to all items in the `TreeView`
2. In the style for the `TreeViewItem` find the `<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">` and replace

   ```
   <Setter TargetName="Bd"
           Property="Background"
           Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground" 
           Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
   ```

   with

   ```
   <Setter TargetName="Bd"
           Property="Background"
           Value="Transparent" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground" 
           Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
   ```

   **NOTE:** Both values (`Foreground` and `Background`) are being replaced!
3. In the style for the `TreeViewItem` find the `<MultiTrigger>` that has a `<Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>` and replace

   ```
   <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
   ```

   with

   ```
   <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
   ```

### Result

Before making the modification the `TreeView` will look like this:

[image]

After making the modification the blue highlighting on the `TreeView` will be gone while it is still available on the `ComboBox`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the extremely detailed answer. It worked like a charm! +1 :)

Comment: Hi again, actually I'm noticing something strange happening - which I'm hoping should be failry simple to solve, and originate from the template. For some reason after clicking on an element in the TreeView, part of the background of that element turns gray. I've added a screenshot in the question to reflect this.

Comment: It actually seems to occur when I click outside the TreeView

Comment: I cannot reproduce that issue. What controls do you actually have inside the items?

Comment: Each TreeViewItem has a number of textboxes, comboboxes and labels

Comment: Seems that one of them is responsible for this. The one in my example simply contains a `ComboBox` with no special style.

Comment: The interesting thing is that this issue was non-existant before applying this custom template :/

Comment: Try to remove all controls from the tree view items. Then add them back, one by one - and see what happens. You also can use a software like XAMLSpy to see what is actually causing the grey color.

Comment: You need to adjust the background of MultiTrigger IsSelect = true as well which is right under that Trigger you mention above and all will be well :)

Comment: Thanks @Maverik and Spontifixus!

Comment: @Maverik Obviously scanning the code for at least ten times didn't work for me - Thank you for pointing that `MultiTrigger` out! I have edited my answer accordingly.